# List of the Latest NuGet Packages for ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am still using Visual Studio 2012, creating ASP.Net MVC 4 applications.

When I create a new project, many (all) of the default added NuGet packages are out of date. If I go to the package manager console and submit a:

```
Update-Package
```

command, then everything updates just fine, but the project will no longer run. You can spend the next several hours then trying to recover from that state. It is unlikely you will succeed.

Example, the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages project is included by default with a new MVC4 "Internet" project. The version installed is 2.0.20710.0.

If I update that to the latest, I get version 3.2.2 (as of right now. You, future person reading this, will no doubt have a different version). The application breaks. It won't work anymore. Good luck ever trying to get it to work again.

Through trial and error, it seems it is safe to install up to version 2.0.30506 before your application dies forever.

What I am wondering is, now that VS2012 and MVC4 is old news, is there a list somewhere of the most up-to-date package versions for the default MVC4 templates that will still work with MVC4?

Maybe just a list of Install-Package commands, such as:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages -Version 2.0.30506
```

(note, I am ignoring for now the security concern of not being able to update to the latest version of a package and getting all the fixes for it... That's probably worth of its own question)

Comment: Well, while it's not technically an answer, your best bet is to just start working with MVC5 for new projects. Not all users are lucky enough to be able to side-step the issue that way, but Visual Studio 2012 has MVC5 tooling available, and really if you *can* work with MVC5 you very definitely should. Creating new projects in MVC4 is a bad idea unless you truly have no option (if you only have Visual Studio 2010 and can't upgrade, for example).

Comment: That IS a good answer, actually. I didn't realize 2012 could get MVC5. I thought that was a > VS 2013 only thing.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll make it an answer then.  You can use MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2012 by installing [ASP.NET Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532).

A brief overview of what's included can be found on the [.NET Web Development and Tools Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx). You can also view the [full release notes](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20131-for-visual-studio-2012).